# How to confgure spring unmarshaller to work with list of xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, jboss, unmarshalling

I want to parse my xml files and past in the entities fields.

In my Initializer.class, I have:

```
   private void parseData() {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("parser.xml");
    XMLConverter converter = (XMLConverter) appContext.getBean("XMLConverter");
    //from XML to object
    //Company is an entity
    Company company = null;
    try {
        company = (Company)converter.convertFromXMLToObject(XML_FILE_NAME);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }

    log.info(company);
    log.info("done");
}
```

XMLConverter:

```
public class XMLConverter {


private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(XMLConverter.class);

public Unmarshaller getUnmarshaller() {
    return unmarshaller;
}

public void setUnmarshaller(Unmarshaller unmarshaller) {
    this.unmarshaller = unmarshaller;
}

public Object convertFromXMLToObject(String xmlfile) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is = null;

    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/xmlToParse/companies.xml");
    File file = new File(url.getPath());

    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        return getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(is));
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}}
```

Parser.xml:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="XMLConverter" class="server.XMLConverter">
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
</bean>
<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller" />
```

But it can't find my folder "xmlToParse" (maybe I didn't bean it?).

How to configure unmarshaller right. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has Maven-like structure, then the folder "xmlToParse" should be placed into ${project.home}/src/main/resources directory.